# Set an event to all controls of same type

Tags: wpf, events, controls

In WPF is there a way to set a particular type of event to all controls of the same type. For example, I'm trying to set the MouseLeftButtonDown event on all controls of type TextBlock. Here is what I tried to do which is obviously wrong:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="MouseLeftButtonDown" Value="TextBlock_LeftClick"/>
</Style>
```

Is there a way that this can be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is a way, you can use the `EventSetter` property in the `Style` to set a `EventHandler` for all `Elements` with that style applied

Example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="TextBlock_LeftClick" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I use your method for adding a mouse click Event to an Ellipse but encounter error like this:
'WpfApplication1.App' does not contain a definition for 'Ellipse_LeftClick' and no extension method 'Ellipse_LeftClick' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication1.App' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in a single statement using WPF EventManager

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Hyperlink), 
                                  Hyperlink.ClickEvent, 
                                 new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnHyperlinkClick));
```